# Best way to render two dimensional table in grails

Tags: grails

I need a table to be displayed with from and to headings, I have two lists:

```
list1 = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G]
```

and `list2` is a list of maps

```
list2 = [ [from: A, to: A, val:20],
          [from: A, to: B, val:10],
          [from: A, to: C, val:30],
          [from: B, to: A, val:10],
          [from: B, to: B, val:40] ]
```

The result should be

```
from to A  B  C  D E F G
 A      20 10 30 - - - -
 B      10 40 -  - - - - 
 C      -  -  -  - - - -
 D      -  -  -  - - - -  
 E      -  -  -  - - - -
 F      -  -  -  - - - -
 G      -  -  -  - - - -
```

How can I do that?

Comment: By iterating on list1 i can print column headings and row headings but coming to data i am not sure how to display the value in particular cell, another important thing is these are editable fields i should be able to save data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>from</th>
        <th>to</th>
        <g:each in="${list1}" var="item">
            <th>${item}</th>
        </g:each>
    </tr>
    <g:each in="${list1}" var="fromItem">
        <tr>
            <td>${fromItem}</td>
            <td></td>
            <g:each in="${list1}" var="toItem">
                <td>
                      ${list2.find{it.from==fromItem && it.to==toItem}?.val?:"-"}
                </td>
             </g:each>
         </tr>
     </g:each>
</table>
```